# How to offload react-native images from memory (iOS)?

Tags: image, react-native, memory

I ran into something weird and am not sure if this is a bug or intended feature of react-native `<Image />` and `<ImageBackground />`

Essentially, I opened memory profiler in XCode and got these results
[image]

Each of the spikes comes from using new image and after going through my full app it looks like all of the images are stored in memory and never offloaded, which is concerning since memory usage just grows over time.

Is there a way to offload these images somehow i.e. when `<Image />` component unmount or manually?

**EDIT** These are not network images, they come from ios project's assets folder i.e.

```
<Image source={{ uri: 'my_image' }} />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to see if the components containing the images are unmounted correctly ?

Also the memory usage behaviour of Image component sucks so you might as well give a try to https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image !

Comment: Hey Hugo! Thank you for suggestion, these are not actually network images, I updated my question to reflect that.

Comment: Are these images rendered in `flatlist` items ?

Comment: No, these are used in Views i.e. background images, button images etc... And growth over time happens when I navigate around my app. Each "spike" is when I open a view with image that was not previously viewed, as soon as I navigate through all views of my app and render all possible images memory graph stays flat, not spiking, but also not going down / offloading them, and this is my concern